# Fetch data from DB Tables based on certain condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables Table A and Table B

Table A

```
([Col A1], [Col A2], [Col A3])
```

Table B

```
([Col B1], [Col B2], [Col B3])
```

Now I have a query to fetch data from both the table based on certain conditions

Example:

```
Select a.*,b.[Col B1]
from [Table A] a, [Table B] b
where a.[Col A1]= '0000'
and a.[Col A1] = b.[Col B1]
```

Suppose this query return me 5 records.

```
Record 1 - Col A1 | Col A2 | Col A3 | Col B1
Record 2 - Col A1 | Col A2 | Col A3 | Col B1
Record 3 - Col A1 | Col A2 | Col A3 | Col B1
Record 4 - Col A1 | Col A2 | Col A3 | Col B1
Record 5 - Col A1 | Col A2 | Col A3 | Col B1
```

I have requirement to add below condition

If Table B Col B3 has value (NOT NULL) then in addition to original result add new record like below

```
Record 1 - Col A1 | Col A2 | Col A3 | Col B1
Record 2 - Col A1 | Col A2 | Col A3 | Col B1
Record 3 - Col A1 | Col A2 | Col A3 | Col B1
Record 4 - Col A1 | Col A2 | Col A3 | Col B1
Record 5 - Col A1 | Col A2 | Col A3 | Col B1
**Record 6 - Col A1 | *Col B3* | Col A3 | Col B1**
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Tabla A have two columns or three columns( colA1, colA2, colA3) ?

Comment: 3 columns - colA1, colA2, colA3

Comment: next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) with a schema and some data so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: New learning for me, thx Juan

Comment: I still not clear on what you are asking, So if none of those answer help, you may consider rewrite your question with a better sample.  And maybe use columname that mean something.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking to essentially split a single row into two rows. So you might want a union:

```
select a.ColA1, a.ColA2, a.ColA3, b.ColB1
from TableA a inner join TableB b on b.ColB1 = a.ColA1
where a.ColA1 = '0000'
union all /* presumably you have no duplicates or want to keep them */
select a.ColA1, b.ColB3, a.ColA3, b.ColB1
from TableA a inner join TableB b on b.ColB1 = a.ColA1
where b.ColB3 is not null
```

There are certainly hacks with a single query but it's really not worth the trouble:

```
select
    a.ColA1,
    case when n = 1 then a.ColA2 when n = 2 then b.ColB3 end as ColA2,
    a.ColA3,
    b.ColB1
from
    TableA a inner join TableB on b.ColB1 = a.ColA1,
    (select 1 n union all select 2) as splitter
where
    case
        when n = 1 and a.ColA1 = '0000' then 1
        when n = 2 and b.ColB3 is null then 1
    end = 1
```

You could also look at `unpivot` but I think it's probably overkill also.

Comment: I mean NOT NULL value

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet here is a UNION:

```
Select a.*,b.Col B1
from Table A a, Table B b
where a.Col A1= '0000'
and a.Col A1 = b.Col B1

UNION ALL

Select a.A1, a.B3, a.A3, b.B1
FROM TableA a 
    INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.A1 = b.B1
WHERE <your condition when you want this record>
```

What that `UNION ALL` does is execute a second query and appends the result set of that second query to the result set of your first query. It stacks the result sets.
If your condition is that you want to add a record to your original result set when there is a record that has b.B3 as a Non-Null value, then your WHERE statement on the second query that is being UNION'd in would be:

```
WHERE b.B3 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a UNION would work.  Something like this:

```
SELECT A.A1, A.A2, A.A3, B.B1
FROM A
    INNER JOIN B 
        ON A.A1 = B.B1
WHERE A1 = '0000'

UNION

SELECT A.A1, B.B3, A.A3, B.B1
FROM A
    INNER JOIN B 
        ON A.A1 = B.B1
WHERE A.A1 = '0000' AND B.B3 IS NOT NULL
```